# + sign not working in JavaScript calculation

Tags: javascript, calculation

I am trying to calculate total in my JavaScript calculation. Division, subtraction, and multiplication all are going good, but when I try to add values, it does not work. Here is my JavaScript code

```
function Calc(v) {
  /*Detail Calculation Each Row*/
  var index = $(v).parent().parent().index();

  var qqq1 = document.getElementsByName("qty[]")[index].value;
  var rrr1 = document.getElementsByName("price1[]")[index].value;
  var ddd1 = document.getElementsByName("discunt[]")[index].value;
  var tot4 = (qqq1) + (rrr1 - ddd1)

  document.getElementsByName("tot4[]")[index].value = tot4;

  GetTotal();
```

Comment: All values extracted from HTML elements are strings in JavaScript. + with strings means concatenation. You must convert your data to numbers first.

Comment: You need to convert the values to numbers, otherwise `+` is string concatenation.

Comment: how can i do that sir! can u gave any example

Comment: Also, if it's qty, shouldn't be `qty  *  (price - discount)`?

Comment: @zeroone, no i want to plus it.

Comment: ok, ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯, good luck.

Comment: issue is solved